# How to change HTML element select into sub-menu UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know using native html element **select** can I do this add (submenus)

- Processes

  - lack of process
  - failure to follow process

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

The code above just allows me to define sub-sections, but no seperate menu ui in parent ui? Is there a way I can change this.

thanks

Comment: This is just a dropdownlist! You can not do further, so try make a real menu with ul and li tag.

Comment: its not scalable when you got 20 elements in each drop-down. Its too much repeating code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, standard selects do not allow for sub-menus, but there are some fairly simple jQuery solutions that use unordered lists.

These are both pretty good / simple solutions:

http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.cfm

http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/clickmenu/

Comment: what about the support from browsers? would it run on all?

Comment: Probably. You'd have to test. It's a fairly simple thing so I imagine it'll be compatible with all modern browsers and probably back to at least IE 7 (maybe 6), but IE 6 is down to 0.05% market and 7 is down to 0.1% so thankfully we finally can stop supporting them I think.

Answer (score 0):

Not using native HTML that I'm aware of, however you could use jQuery to do this.

```
<Select id="cartype">
    <option value="Select">Select Car Type</option>
    <option value="Swedish Cars">Swedish Cars</option>
    <option value="German Cars">German Cars</option>
</Select>
<select id="carDetail">
    <option value="unset">Select Car Type First</option>
</select>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $.fn.addOption = function(optText, optValue){
        var option = new Option(optText, optValue);
        return this.append(option);
        };
    $("#cartype").change(function() {
        $("#carDetail option").remove();
        switch ($("#cartype").val())
        {
        case "Swedish Cars":
            $("#carDetail").addOption("Volvo", "volvo");
            $("#carDetail").addOption("Saab", "saab");
            break;
        case "German Cars":
            $("#carDetail").addOption("Mercedes","mercedes");
            $("#carDetail").addOption("Audi","audi");
            break;
        default:
            $("#carDetail").addOption("Select Car Type First","unset");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```